# Imported icon into Visual Studio 2013 looks terrible

Tags: visual-studio, icons

-- I'm using Visual Studio 2013 --

I have an icon with transparent background. It was created in Photoshop as an 8-bit RGB image and exported to .ico via the free telegraphics ICO Format plugin. I saved out 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 64, 96, 128 and 256 resolutions versions and then used another free telegraphics plugin to bundle them into a single .ico file with all the resolutions.

When I use Windows 10 to apply this .ico file as the icon for a shortcut it looks great.  But when I try to import this icon into a Visual Studio C++ project and embed it into my EXE it looks terrible.  By "terrible" I mean it looks choppy/pixelated and there appear to be random colors in several pixels. It just looks awful.

To import into my VS project I right-clicked the project in the VS "Solution Explorer" and chose Add --> Resource. In the Add Resource window I selected "Icon" and then used "Import..." to bring in my .ico file. After the import, I can see all the different resolutions of the icon were found, but like I said - they look terrible. Most of the problems of random colored pixels appear to take place along transparent edges of the image. (I have text with transparent background).

And when I actually build the EXE, it appears Windows only shows the smallest resolution (16x16) version of icon no matter what my view thumbnail size is.

This is only a problem when trying to use my icon in Visual Studio and building the EXE.  Like I said, if I wait until after building the EXE and then use Windows to manually assign this icon it looks fine.

Comment: I can suggest a few things: 1. Is your .ico file 160px X 160px ? This is usually the standard for .ico icon files. 2. Or maybe check the [Visual Studio Website](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/). 3. Finally what about updating your visual studio to the latest edition? maybe it's just a VS 2013 thing ? Let me know if you find anything :)

Comment: I created my icon to have several sizes based on the info I could find. I tried in VS 2015 and it had the same problem.